# Create random points not creating enough points-ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, point, random

I'm creating random survey points within polygons based on how large each patch is, about 1 point per hectare. The points also need to be at least 175m apart. Since the plots are weird shapes, I figure I won't be able to fit quite that many but the program will fit what it can. Yet when I run it, it only places 2 or 3 points in polygons that should fit 20 or 30. It throws the error that it couldn't fit the requested number of points, but even the closest are over 200m apart.

[image: Create random points window filled out]

It seems like the program thinks there isn't enough space, even when there is. Any ideas why this would happen? Let me know if there's more information you need to understand the problem!

[image: Example of 2 polygons with generated random points]

Comment: So what are the typically values in your Hectares field?

Comment: They're between 2 and 46, the polygons shown here are 27, 29, and 9 hectares

Comment: Is it a scale issue, so for example your hectare field contains 27 which would be 270,000 square metres and you polygons' actual area is say 1,000 square metres and with your minimum distance in place only 2 or 3 points are created?

Comment: Are you asking if the hectare field has the incorrect size? I don't think that's the issue, I've seen some of these plots on the ground so I don't think ArcMap miscalculated the area

Comment: If you don't impose a minimum distance between points do you get the expected number of points in each polygon based on the **count** in your hectare field?

Comment: Yes I tried that and it puts the correct number of points in!